# Ubuntu 16.04.4 windows redraw with Nvidia drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have tried to install Ubuntu 16.04.4 (16.04.5 won't even boot, black screen after Ubuntu logo). The system works fine with nouveau drivers.

However, after an install of the Nvidia official drivers (with each version above 370), the window becomes heavily laggy. When I move windows around, or scroll, lag is noticeable in window redrawing (like changing one picture to another). If I change the performance profile and make it to use Intel's graphics lag disappears.

My laptop is Dell Inspiron Gaming 15:
Intel Core i7-7700HQ,
16 GB RAM,
Nvidia GeForce GTX1050Ti.